# Get the key from map of map

Tags: json, dictionary, groovy

I have a map like so:

```
[One:[example:value1, example2:value2] ,Two[example 1:value3, example2:value4]]
```

I'm am matching value1 from a value in another map, but I need to get the keys,either One or Two depending on if it is a match.

So if I say:

```
if( value1.equals (otherMapValue))
    Return One
```

This map is from a json response so if there is a better way to do this besides a map  I can change it. Sorry for the formatting I'm using my phone

Comment: What is the input? You get something like `value1` and you need to find the keys?

Comment: Value1 will match a value from another map, and I have some each closures to check if they match which they do, so I need to get the key of value, but not example1 I need the "master key" which would be One..not sure if this is possible honestly..the above map is a json response and the other map is a configuration map..

Comment: @naffy_naffy show your whole matching code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
def someMethod(valueFromOthermap) {
    def map = [
        One: [example1: 'value1', example2:'value2'],
        Two: [example1: 'value3', example2:'value4']
    ]

    map.findResults { k, v ->
        valueFromOthermap in v.values() ? k : null
    }
}

assert someMethod('value1') == ['One']
```

If you are looking for the first matching key instead of a list of keys, then use `findResult` instead of `findResults`, everything else remains unchanged.

**UPDATE**:
Regarding JSON to `Map` parsing, a JSON resonse can be easily parsed to `Map` as shown below:

```
Map responseMap = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText( jsonResponseString )
```